# Для чего используется ChangeTrackerClear()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Для чего здесь может использоваться ChangeTrackerClear()?

В интернете нашел, что он используется для

- Для отмены изменений
- Для производительности, очистка ChangeTracker уменьшит объем памяти, используемый контекстом

  ```
   [Fact]
    public async void TestUpdateAdd()
    {
        var testHelper = new TestHelper();
        var categoryRepository = testHelper.CategoryRepository;
        var category = categoryRepository.GetByTitleAsync("Nature").Result;

        categoryRepository.ChangeTrackerClear();
        category.Title = "The Nature";
        var album = new Album { Title = "Night", Cost = "2000 руб", Description = "Night pics" };
        category.AddAlbum(album);



   await categoryRepository.UpdateAsync(category);

    Assert.Equal("The Nature", categoryRepository.GetByTitleAsync("The Nature").Result.Title);
  ```

  }

Метод ChangeTrackerClear в классе categoryRespository:

```
public void ChangeTrackerClear()
{
    // сброс отслеживания изменений
    _context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
}
```

**Какой смысл здесь сбрасывать изменения?**

Comment: Код наделяется смыслом программистом.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что в приведённом методе отмена изменений необходима для исключения влияния уже сделанных изменений на результат теста.